# IKEv2 Using Different PSKs

Tags: authentication, ipsec, ike

We're setting up some new tunnels and have been told to use IKEv2. I understand that IKEv2 allows different authentication methods, e.g. one side using PSK and the other using a certificate. We don't have a PKI so it'll have to be PSK for now.

I can see it's possible to use the same PSK (like IKEv1) or different PSKs on either end such that:

- Device1: local psk = Key1, remote psk = Key2
- Device2: local psk = Key2, remote psk = Key1

So Q1: does this actually add any extra security? I guess not since both sides need to know both keys somebody getting access to Device1, say, could discover Key1 and Key2 anyway.

Just trying to figure out the point of using two different ones? Are both PSKs are used to set up a connection and both must be right? Or is only the initiator's OR responder's PSK used?

I guess we will just configure them all the same but the question came up and I had no idea what the answer was. I've looked through what I think are the relevant RFCs (6617 and 7296) but I can't find an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't increase the security. As you point out, both peers have to know both PSKs.

> Are both PSKs are used to set up a connection and both must be right? Or is only the initiator's OR responder's PSK used?

Each peer would use its "local" PSK to produce the `AUTH` payload in the `IKE_AUTH` message it sends.

And each peer would use the "remote" PSK to verify that the received `AUTH` payload was produced with knowledge of the corresponding PSK (which in turn requires that same PSK).